# how to loop and append a <br> tag to each of array of anchor of tags?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an number of achor elements, how to loop through each and add a 
 tag ?
it's like this,

```
<a id="fbutton" href="http://www.facebook.com" title="fb" name="fb[]">
 <img alt="fb" src="/images/icons/fb.jpg">
</a>
```

why do i want to add a br tag, because this button is too close to another button with another array name

Comment: why can't you use css to separate the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ***[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)***

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).after('<br>');
});
```

Or just `$('a').after('<br>');` if you don't need to do extra logic in the each callback function.

Comment: the <br/> doesn't reflect to the next page when i click the pagination button

Comment: @sasori If you refresh the content by ajax, you need to add the br again for the new html content, but instead of doing this, you should use CSS instead to achieve your job. Add `<br>` by javascript is a dirty fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try this , no looping is required ..

```
 $("a").after("<br/>");
```

​

For reference http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: This will append <br> after the image, not the a tag.

Comment: there are other links in the page with different names

Answer (score 1):

Give all `a` elements you want to loop through a `class`, then use:

```
$("a.classyougavethem").after("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to loop it...

```
$('a').after('<br>');
```